# Pagination for jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I have created a datatable using jQuery. Below is the HTML code for the same:

```
<table id="md-transaction-table" class="wide100 margin-bottom-1">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Payment Date</th>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Statement Number</th>
           <th>Payment Transaction ID</th>
           <th>Amount</th>
           <th>Payment Method</th>
           <th>User</th>
           <th>Payment Status</th>   
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And below is the jQuery code for the same:

```
$('#md-transaction-table').dataTable({
    "data":json,
    "dom": 't',
    "bSort":false,
    "pageLength": 8,
    "paging": true,
    "bPaginate":true,
    "pagingType":"full_numbers",
    "columns": [
        {"data": "paymentDate"},
        {"data": "description"},
        {"data": "statementNumber"},
        {"data": "transactionId"},
        {"data": "amount"},
        {"data": "paymentMethod"},
        {"data": "user"},
        {"data": "paymentStatus"}

    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {className: "pad-md-left-p-10 pad-top-bottom-p-10", "targets": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
        ]

}); // End of datatable function
```

Now I need to put a pagination below the table. Something like this:

[image: Pagination]

My requirement is that, initially I need to show only 8 rows in the table. When the user will click on next button, then it must hide previous 8 rows and display next 8 rows. Can you tell me how can we do so? I am using default pagination feature of datatable. But pagination is not showing up. Can you tell me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried default pagination functionality of datatables? [example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

Comment: @Buksy: I have tried. See the edited code. But pagination is not showing up.

Comment: You need to add pagination to the `dom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `dom` option from datatables initialization and pagination will work.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/umbjtceg/)